# How can I convert postgres database to JSON file?

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql, flutter

I'm working on flutter mobile application which should be attached (connected) with the web platform that I developed with laravel, I want to generate JSON file from Postgres dynamically , I mean when I update any thing in the database it will be updated in the mobile also and I need to display the data in the mobile application.
I followed this tutorial and I understood that I must convert the database or the tables into json file. How I'm going to do it please, it's the first time I'm working with Flutter and json.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7b7_Nq7XSs&list=PLK7ZDJTUghFAmRR4mueiai7zq1RJfMQ62&index=11&t=1s

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting started, please take your time and get yourself familiar with the basics and how flutter treats the data coming from a database.

Also something you should have been reading **and** understood is [JSON and serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).

Based on that it is not advisable that you retrieve JSON right from the database. Instead, JSON serialization happens in one way or another inside flutter using one of the recommended approaches.

Specifically for working with PostgreSQL, there seems to be a [decent tutorial](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-how-to-do-crud-with-postgresql-part-1-57d8d3652a31).

Please keep in mind that what you actually have asked for here (*"... database to JSON file"*) indicates you really want a *file output*, which is completely contrary to the API that you're going to provide with flutter.

Of course it is possible to query PostgreSQL and get the result already in JSON format, but that then also means you won't be able to work with the data model inside flutter.

However, if you finally know what you are doing, here is a way to get the result of any PostgreSQL query directly as JSON:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(t) FROM (
    SELECT ...whatever you can think of...
) AS t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel version greater than 5, you can use [API resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) to create API and connection to PostgreSQL(https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database). It is so simple to create API using laravel API resources. Then in Flutter only thing you have to do is request endpoints you have created using laravel.